# Different styles dependent on displayed elements

Tags: css, sass

I have an element which could contain **one**, **two** or **three** buttons.

When i have only **one** button, then there is **no** margin to the right

When i have **two** buttons, then the first button gets a right margin

And when i've **three** buttons, the first and the second button get a right margin

**What i have tried:**

- The :only-child covers my needs for only one button.
- The sibling selector works pretty good but is limited when it comes to three buttons

Would love to read your solutions for this :)

**EDIT:**

Here comes a screen-capture of the page:
It shows the three possibilities. The container could either contain one, two or three buttons. I have already figured out how to edit the space around two buttons but how do i manage this for three?

[image: This is a Gif of the three buttons]

Comment: It will be better if you show with pictures what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:last-child` selector and have css that looks like this:

```
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

When you only have one button, it will be the last element, and therefore won't have any margin. Then for two and three buttons, the last one won't have margin.

The `:last-child` selector works for IE9 and above.

Comment: ahhh, thanks mate. It has been a long day at the office :p How could i forget about the magical css selectors